# Does selenium(codeception) still support Firefox ?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, codeception

Hi everyone im having problem with running test on firefox. I did read that firefox is no longer support, but i am not sure. Does anyone know if it is true ?

```
Selenium build info: version: '3.6.0'
Firefox Version: 57.0
```

Answer (score 0):

from Firefox 55 onwards, Selenium IDE will no longer work.
Please refer this link [link](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2017/08/09/firefox-55-and-selenium-ide/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20Selenium%20%28The%20Official%20Selenium%20Blog%29)

Comment: Oh, i didn't know, Thank you :)

Comment: You can accept my answer so other can get help from it :)